# I added a material but it is a little bit distorted, why?

Tags: materials, node-editor

I also tried to add a Mapping node but nothing changed
[image: this is the node map]

Comment: I also noticed that at the top of the mash the material is not distorted, only at bottom / at the side of the elephant (like you can see in the image)

Comment: Try changing your texture coordinates from *Generated* to *UV* If the material has details, it will need to be UV unwrapped.